# Finding nodes between two nodes

Tags: python

I wrote dijkstras algorithm in python and get the following output for input G:

```
G={'A': {('B', 1.0), ('C', 5.0)},
   'B': {('D', 2.0), ('E', 4.0), ('A', 1.0)},
   'C': {('A', 5.0), ('E', 3.0), ('D', 2.0)},
   'D': {('E', 1.0), ('C', 2.0), ('B', 2.0)},
   'E': {('D', 1.0), ('B', 4.0), ('C', 3.0)}}
```

i.e distance between A and B is 1.0,A and C is 5.0 and so on.
`shortestPath(G,"A")` gives me:

```
Output: {'E': 4.0, 'D': 3.0, 'A': 0, 'C': 5.0, 'B': 1.0}
```

Now i should use this output to find all the nodes between two nodes for example: `shortestPathnew(G,"A","C")`

The shortest path between A and C in this example is 5.0 and it goes through A->B->D->C. So the output should be (5.0, [A,B,D,C]) using basic for loop without using built-in functions like .iterations, .keys, yield, sort and so on. I am stuck in this part and any help would be helpful.

I tried using an example code online but I'm unable to modify it for my requirement:

```
def shortestPathnew(G,start,end):
    """
    Find a single shortest path from the given start node
    to the given end node.  The output is a list of the node in order along the shortest path."""

    final_distances,predecessors = ShortestPath(graph,start)
    path = []
    while 1:
        path.append(end)
        if end == start: break
        end = predecessors[end]
    path.reverse()
    return path
```

i have to implement it without using .append,.reverse

Comment: Can you show the code you currently have? Otherwise we can't improve it

Comment: I have edited and updated the code

Comment: Actually, A->C is already 5, so Dijkstra's algorithm won't update the distance. Try using A->C being 6.

Comment: Do you have to be able to handle directed graphs, or will they all be undirected graphs?

Comment: It should handle directed graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell based on the example code, I don't think your `shortestPath` method and the one the example code uses return the same things. I'm guessing it is returning something like:

```
({'E': 4.0, 'D': 3.0, 'A': 0, 'C': 5.0, 'B': 1.0}, {'B': 'A', 'D': 'B', 'C': 'A', 'E':'D', 'A': None})
```

So not only does it have the final distances, it also includes each node and the node that precedes it (I don't know if it would include the start node or not).

If you can generate that in your `shortestPath` method, then it shouldn't be too hard to change the example code to use only basic `for` loops. Here's one possibility:

```
final_distances,predecessors = ShortestPath(graph,start)
path = end
while end != start:
    end = predecessors[end]
    path = '%s->%s' % (end, path)
return path
```

Rather than storing the results in a list and appending each new node to the end of that list, it is easy to create a string where you are prepending to it each time. You can do something similar with a list, if that is what you need to return:

```
final_distances,predecessors = ShortestPath(graph,start)
path = [end]
while end != start:
    end = predecessors[end]
    path = [end] + path
return path
```

Here I am initializing path to be a list just containing `end`, and at each step of the loop it finds the predecessor of the current node and prepending it to path.

Comment: Using %s in a string says that you are going to insert the value of a variable into the string. This is basically equivalent to `end + '->' + path`.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any possibility to replace "path = '%s->%s' % (end, path)" with a simple loop to store the contents in the list??

Comment: @Rachel added how to do it with a list.